# Program does not load if Speech Recognition Language is set to anything other than English - US

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.0, voice-recognition

I have added a speech recognition feature to my program. However, if I try to run the program and the language in the Speech Properties is set to anything other than "Microsoft Speech Recognizer 8.0 for Windows (English - US), the program fails to load.

I would like to have it so that the program will load no matter which language is selected.

The code for my voice command is as follows:

```
vcstat.Text = "Voice Control Enabled";
            recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
            recognizer.SpeechDetected += recognizer_SpeechDetected;
            recognizer.SpeechRecognitionRejected += recognizer_SpeechRecognitionRejected;
            recognizer.SpeechRecognized += recognizer_SpeechRecognized;  
        GrammarBuilder grammar = new GrammarBuilder();
            grammar.Append(new Choices("Cut", "Copy", "Paste", "Select All Text", "Print", "Unselect All Text", "Delete", "Save", "Save As", "Open", "New", "Close Basic Word Processor"));
            recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(grammar));
```

There is some more code, but that's to do with the actual commands, so I don't think it's necessary to post it here.

If somebody could help me figure out a way to allow the program to start, regardless of the Speech Recognition Engine in use, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What does "fails to load" mean?  Are you getting an error message?  Do you have the necessary language packs installed for the languages you want to support?

Comment: When I say "fails to load" I mean when I try to build the program, I get an error stating that "The language for the grammar does not match the language of the speech recognizer." I need it to be able to use the other Speech Recognizer languages..

Answer (score 0):

You can only use Speech Recognition in a different language if a MUI language pack is installed on the client's computer for one of the supported languages.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-7-speech-recognition-language-selection/0a859099-a76d-4799-abe9-847997399927

Comment: Okay... Seems a bit odd. I'm going to try and make myself a bit clearer (I'm not sure how clear I was before..): If the client has their PC set up using French language options, I want the program to load the correct grammar/speech recognizer.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, how do I set the language to `Microsoft Speech Recognizer 8.0 for Windows (English - US)`? I can't find anything online showing me how to set it.